# "Unable to get template type with legacy id" error

Tags: 2011, templating, 2013, upgrade

I am working with the XPM in Tridion 2013 at the moment. I want to change the page template of one of my pages but when I click on the drop-down, there is an error notification popping up. It says:

`Unable to get template type with legacy id: 1. Please check that legacy pack is installed. Unable to get template type Unable to get template type with id: 1`.

The publication containing my page is created in 2011 and I think that this might be the problem. I made another publication after I've installed 2013 and inside this publication everything is fine. There is no error when I try to change the template and the templates are shown in the list.

Here is a short video of the described issue - http://screencast.com/t/Fl2qcV62lQ

Does any of you guys had the same problem? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Judging by the error message the template is based on legacy (VBscript/Jscript or XSLT) and you didn't install the legacy pack?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is VBscript templates in your migrated 2011 publication. This can easily be fixed by installing the Legacy Pack.

You can install the legacy back by running the Tridion 2013 CM installer with an additional option. This allow you to install the legacy pack. For more info see the [Decide if you want to install legacy features](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/task_BA1450E7474241D48D980A6E3CE8FB86) section of the manual (login required).

> SDLTridion2013CM.exe LEGACY_VISIBLE=TRUE

Every upgraded Tridion 2013 CM implementation needs to have the Legacy pack on the Content Manager servers, unless you are absolutely sure there are no legacy items in the database. Even one unused legacy item can raise errors like this because without the legacy pack the CM cannot read those legacy items.

In your case a VBscript item (legacy id 1) causes this error, of course there might be other legacy items (VBscript templates, VBscript TBBs, JScript templates or XSLT templates) in the same CM database.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and descriptive answer, Jan! It solved the problem.

Comment: +1 and good point on the database. Even if the CM is a new install, we may still need the Legacy Pack because of what's in the database.

Comment: @Alvin: I agree. Confusing terminology... The CM server software could be a new install, but with an upgraded database I would still consider it an upgraded CM. The CM (Content Manager) consists of software, databases and configuration.