# Legacy items and Content Porter 2013

Tags: 2013, content-porter-2013

Can a Content Porter 2013 package with legacy items be imported on a Tridion 2013 CM server without legacy pack installed?

I wonder if the import operation would fail with errors like [Stefan's legacy item problem](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/756/unable-to-get-template-type-with-legacy-id-error) or would the Content Porter Server ignore the legacy items?

Of course I am not trying to sneak legacy items in a CM without legacy pack installed, I am just wondering if it could lead to any issues.

Comment: definitely worth a try I would say, but I have a feeling that without the legacy pack, the file extensions for legacy templates are not available, so CP will certainly fail if it tries to import them (might be smart enough to skip them)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can confirm that the import will fail if you try to move legacy items to a CM server without a legacy pack installed. It is possible to skip importing these items, but this will cause a bunch of dependency failures on following imports. Sadly, unless you're willing to modernize your existing content, the legacy pack is required to import content from 2011 implementations, as even the default templates from 2011 include VBScript.

Comment: It makes perfect sense - you wouldn't be able to _use_ those legacy items in the target system... thanks for confirming it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I think it's best the CM explicitly fails like you confirmed, so no unexpected results. If you migrate from Tridion 2011 to Tridion 2013 it is advised to install the legacy pack. If you are absolutely sure your 2011 implementation has no legacy items, then you could skip the legacy pack. Btw, it is possible to install and uninstall the legacy pack later.