# WorkFlow Error in Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: workflow

I am getting the below mentioned error in workflow. I am using the fresh copy of Tridion 2013 SP1.

> Tridion.ContentManager.TypeRegistration.WorkflowScriptTypeRegistrationException: Workflow Script Type with Name 'VBScript' was not found in the configuration file.

Answer (score 4):

That's a simple one - you installed Tridion 2013 SP1 without Legacy support. SDL Tridion 2013 introduced a new model for workflow that does not use VBScript for automatic activities ("Bundle Workflow").

If you need VBScript support, you need to re-run your installer with `LEGACY_VISIBLE=TRUE` (as described in [this answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/759/33)), and then select to enable Legacy features in the feature selection screen of the installer.

Comment: I am not using the Bundle workflow concept. I am using the same old workflow automatic activity. Do i still need to install the legacy pack ?

Comment: If you need VBScript support, you need the Legacy Pack. If you only use Bundle Workflows, then you don't need the Legacy pack.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you've switched on the 'enforce workflow' at a schema level you will also need to ensure you select an appropriate (and by appropriate I mean none-legacy) workflow such as described [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13232/unable-to-remove-legacy-workflow-activities).