# Does Manual Decision activity uses VBScript?

Tags: 2013, workflow, vbscript

We are using Tridion 2013 SP1 and implementing workflow.

We are getting the VB Script error explained below in Manual Decision activity.

[WorkFlow Error in Tridion 2013 SP1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5006/workflow-error-in-tridion-2013-sp1)

We have not implemented anything related to VB Script.

Does Manual Decision activity uses VBScript?

If Yes, Do i need to install the legacy pack?

Comment: Jitender, did you upgrade from 2009/2011 to 2013? If so then maybe you have existing items using VBScript?

Comment: Depends on the type of workflow process you use - if you use Component, Page or Template Process then you need VBScript. C# activities are only available for Task/Bundle Workflow Processes

Comment: @Kunal: I have not upgraded from 2009/11. It is a fresh install of 2013 SP1 .

Comment: @Nuno: I am using Component, Page workflow process so i need to install VB Script pack as well on 2013 SP1 also ?

Comment: Yes - that's exactly what I said...

Answer (score 1):

1. You need the Legacy Package installed in order to execute VB Script in your Activities.
2. You need to make sure that your activities script type is VB Script Legacy.
3. It seems that while migrating you still have code in your activities that uses VB Script.
4. You should consider migrating it to External Activities (preferred) or C#.

Comment: We are using the fresh install of Tridion 2013 SP1.We are not using any VB Script activity .All my activity uses External Activity not VBScript. My code throws error in Manual Decision activity.Does manual Decision activity uses VB Script internally ?