# Unable to remove legacy workflow activities

Tags: workflow, vbscript

We have an SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 implementation *without* the VBScript Legacy pack installed as we only require workflow with Bundles. However, it appears that a couple of Activities have been left-over from the initial upgrade - relating to workflow instances using VBScript.

I'm unable to progress the Activities as I receive the message

> workflow script type with name 'vbscript' was not found in the
>   configuration file

*BUT* I'm also unable to delete them. Is there anything using the core service that I can use to remove the association so I can delete the activities?

We're working through the documentation and will update this is we see anything more...

As this is also in the PRD environment, I'm looking for a way to avoid having to re-run the installer with `LEGACY_VISIBLE=TRUE` (as described [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/756/unable-to-get-template-type-with-legacy-id-error/759#759))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had selected to enforce Bundle Workflow Processes at a schema level. As such, the GUI selects a default Workflow Process for the Bundle which we didn't change and just saved.

After changing the Preferred Workflow Process for this Bundle to a workflow we designed without legacy scripts etc. all was well.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Workflow script types are registered in Tridion.ContentManager.config.

You could temporarily add an entry for VBScript (using a bogus executor type) so that the VBScript activities can be loaded and deleted.

Comment: Thanks for this Rick - we've a call with Support so I've to see what they come back with - but I will test this in my VM soon as and confirm if this worked.